# Cant Run Elasticsearch on cpanel (Linux)

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, installation, cpanel

I am having trouble in installing the Elasticsearch on my live webserver. I have terminal access. I downloaded the elasticsearch on my root directory (public_html) and extracted it as per elastic documnents.

When on terminal i try to run elasticsearch i get the following error

[image]

Kindly let me know what can i do and what is the right way to install and run elastic search on the live web server.

Thank You

Comment: last line is pointing to out of memory error. how much is the storage space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of disk storage, it's because of less RAM available in your system and by default as stated in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html) Elastic doc.

> By default, Elasticsearch tells the JVM to use a heap with a minimum
>   and maximum size of 1 GB. When moving to production, it is important
>   to configure heap size to ensure that Elasticsearch has enough heap
>   available.

So, Looks like there is very less RAM(memory) available in your system, **which is leading to very less heap available for Elasticsearch process which in turn causing [OOM error](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-outofmemoryerror-exception-java/).**

## Solution:

1. First check the available RAM(memory) of your server by using below command, which will show the total and available RAM in GB.

   free -g

The output of the above command will look like

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              1           0           1           0           0           1
Swap:             0           0           0
```

**Make sure at least, you have a total of 1 GB of RAM available for Elasticsearch process and then restart, it should work.**

Comment: i applied your command and i found out folliwing results
             total     used    free   shared   buff/cache   avaialble

Mem:     15         3          0          0                10           10
Swap:      0           0         0

Comment: lets continue chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210928/room-for-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-kool-coder

Comment: are you there? @opster Elasticsearch Ninja