# elastichead is not connecting with elasticsearch docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

my elastichead is not connecting even when my elasticsearch container is running.
I can't understand the problem.

```
(env) C:\Users\shubh\Desktop\react-django\emt_api\emt_assets>docker ps -a
```

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE
> COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
> NAMES 117ba87ad874        mdillon/postgis:11
> "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 hours ago         Up 4 hours
> 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp             postgres 70b6527e1046        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.8
> "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   9 hours ago         Up 5 hours
> 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   elasticsearch

but after running elastichead head there is still no connection.
my system is windows 10 home edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was working with the docker toolbox which includes oracle virtual box. There you can see your docker machine settings.
just stop your docker machine with command in docker quickstart terminal

```
docker-machine stop <docker-machine name>
```

Then in your oracle virtual box..go to System>Advanced> Increase the memory to 4gb(4096mb)
And start docker-machine with command in docker quickstart terminal

```
docker-machine start <docker-machine name>
```

and work with your container.

Answer (score 1):

Its very common for ES process to die due to [out of memory error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory).  Please refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61023162/4039431) SO answer for more info.